# Condition in ng- class not working

Tags: angularjs, ng-class, angularjs-1.5

**AngularJS**

I have scenario of applying class based on a condition in which I'm storing the value in rootscope dynamically and evaluating in html angular expression but still not working

```
<li role="presentation" style="width:200px" ng-class="{active: true, inactive: false}[{{vm.$rootScope.currentPage}}==1]"><a href="#/create">Create</a></li>
```

In inspect element if I check I can see 1==1 but still class is not getting active and **if I remove {{vm.$rootScope.currentPage}} and place 1 it is working**

I tried this also

```
<li role="presentation" style="width:200px" ng-class="{'active':2=={{vm.$rootScope.currentPage}} }"><a href="#/include">include</a></li>
```

Same thing with this also I can see 2==2 but still not activating and **if  Istatically place 2==2 it is working**

Answer (score 4):

You're writing it wrong, do like this:

```
ng-class="{'active': true, 'inactive': false}
```

The class name first then the condition.

And for this:

```
ng-class="{'active': 2 === vm.$rootScope.currentPage}"
```

No extra brackets inside because it's already an expression.

Comment: Not Working , ng-class="{active: 'true', inactive: 'false'}[1==1]     -1st code in inspectElement ,      ng-class={'active':2===vm.$rootScope.currentPage }"

Comment: Don't wrap your booleans in quotes. Do it the way I showed.

Comment: ya even I removed quotes same output , problem is not with those expression is evaluated  but some late binding happening I guess because when I statically place expression it's working

Comment: Then that's a whole other question then, it seems like this one has been resolved. If you need help with the other thing too post a new question :)

Comment: wrapping the class name is only required when the class name has a hyphen.

`{active:true}` should work
`{'active-more':true}` requires the single quotes