# Angular Expression in ng-class evaluating after css is applied (late binding)

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-class

I have an `ng-class` where class is dynamically loaded i.e evaluating `$rootscope` in expression,  late binding is happening

```
<li role="presentation" style="width:200px" ng-class="{active: true, inactive: false}[{{vm.$rootScope.currentPage}}==1]"><a href="#/create">Create</a></li>
```

Here `{{vm.$rootScope.currentPage}}` expression is evaluating after class for the control is loaded in place of that if give 1 it is working or and if I check in inspect element I can see `[1==1]` i.e  `{{vm.$rootScope.currentPage}}` this is returning correct value but class is not getting applied

Can refer this [Condition in ng- class not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36574692/condition-in-ng-class-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `[vm.$rootScope.currentPage===1]` instead of `[{{vm.$rootScope.currentPage}}==1]` . no need to use `{{}}` in `[]`

and need to change

`ng-class="{true: 'active', false:'inactive' }"` instead of `ng-class="{'active': true , 'inactive':false }"`

for `ng-class="{true: 'active', false:'inactive' }[vm.$rootScope.currentPage==1]"` class applied way

if expression value is **true** then apply class **active**

if expression value is **false** then apply class **inactive**

so use:

```
<li role="presentation" style="width:200px" ng-class="{true: 'active', false:'inactive' }[vm.$rootScope.currentPage===1]"><a href="#/create">Create</a></li>
```

Also can use ternary operator in `ng-class` like: `ng-class="vm.currentPage===1? 'active': 'inactive'"`

```
<li role="presentation" style="width:200px" ng-class="vm.currentPage===1? 'active': 'inactive'">
      <a href="#/create">Create</a>
 </li>
```

[PLUNKER DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/3nNV2vBtXdGh0b3IMqTX?p=preview)

Comment: Not Working , in inspect element I can see in place of [{{vm.$rootScope.currentPage===1}}] this as [true]  but still class is not applying because expression evaluation is done after class is applied to that  control

Comment: Updated my answer and added plunker demo @sudhir

Comment: Awesome bro, actually instead in click function I was maintaining a global variable and updating that in individual controllers which is getting updated after class is applied. Any this worked as I'm using click function and passing params which is better way, Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Actually I added two button to change page and check change.You can use as you need and I gave valid expression to set class. can accept if helped you:)

Comment: Can Accept but the question is why isn't working when evaluating rootscope i.e its getting updated but that expression is evaluated after class is applied . However, solution you provided is the best for my scenario

Answer (score 0):

Try this- `ng-class="vm.$rootScope.currentPage==1?'active':'inactive'"`.

You're adding multiple extra layers of work for Angular, just for a simple true/false test. Most notably, you had a `{{ }}` expression *in an ng directive*. AFAIK, all of these already track the expression you put in, and adding a `{{ }}` just adds more that it needs to watch.

You may also be able to refer it it simply as `currentPage`, instead of `vm.$rootScope.currentPage`, but that depends if you've set up the scoping for whatever component this is.

Comment: It is not working and  if you do not put code  expressions ng-class will not treat as angular expression especially ng-class , ng-show and ng-hide AFAIK

Comment: `vm.$rootScope.currentPage==1?'active':'inactive'` is an expression. I think you might be referencing things wrong.